# Delphi - Declare Matrix const

Tags: delphi

Editing my Question.

I'll be specific.

How can I declare the code below as `const` instead of `var`?
(I couldn't get Cube example)

```
 var
 Matrix : array of array of string;

 SetLength(Matrix, 8, 8);
 Matrix[0,0]:='A0';Matrix[0,1]:='A1';Matrix[0,2]:='A2';Matrix[0,3]:='A3';Matrix[0,4]:='A4';Matrix[0,5]:='A5';Matrix[0,6]:='A6';Matrix[0,7]:='A7';
 Matrix[1,0]:='B0';Matrix[1,1]:='B1';Matrix[1,2]:='B2';Matrix[1,3]:='B3';Matrix[1,4]:='B4';Matrix[1,5]:='B5';Matrix[1,6]:='B6';Matrix[1,7]:='B7';
 Matrix[2,0]:='C0';Matrix[2,1]:='C1';Matrix[2,2]:='C2';Matrix[2,3]:='C3';Matrix[2,4]:='C4';Matrix[2,5]:='C5';Matrix[2,6]:='C6';Matrix[2,7]:='C7';
 Matrix[3,0]:='D0';Matrix[3,1]:='D1';Matrix[3,2]:='D2';Matrix[3,3]:='D3';Matrix[3,4]:='D4';Matrix[3,5]:='D5';Matrix[3,6]:='D6';Matrix[3,7]:='D7';
 Matrix[4,0]:='E0';Matrix[4,1]:='E1';Matrix[4,2]:='E2';Matrix[4,3]:='E3';Matrix[4,4]:='E4';Matrix[4,5]:='E5';Matrix[4,6]:='E6';Matrix[4,7]:='E7';
 Matrix[5,0]:='F0';Matrix[5,1]:='F1';Matrix[5,2]:='F2';Matrix[5,3]:='F3';Matrix[5,4]:='F4';Matrix[5,5]:='F5';Matrix[5,6]:='F6';Matrix[5,7]:='F7';
 Matrix[6,0]:='G0';Matrix[6,1]:='G1';Matrix[6,2]:='G2';Matrix[6,3]:='G3';Matrix[6,4]:='G4';Matrix[6,5]:='G5';Matrix[6,6]:='G6';Matrix[6,7]:='G7';
 Matrix[7,0]:='H0';Matrix[7,1]:='H1';Matrix[7,2]:='H2';Matrix[7,3]:='H3';Matrix[7,4]:='H4';Matrix[7,5]:='H5';Matrix[7,6]:='H6';Matrix[7,7]:='H7';
```

Comment: What is your question. This is exceedingly unclear.

Comment: your matrix array can be easily created as a constant - just see `Maze: TCube` example at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declared_Constants#Array_Constants

Comment: I saw the exemple and i'm still confused in the way it operates, can you help me on the first lines of my matrix? right now it is like this :

    var Matrix : array of array : string 
           SetLength(Matrix, 8, 8);
     Matrix[0,0]:='A0';Matrix[0,1]:='A1';Matrix[0,2]:='A2';Matrix[0,3]:='A3';Matrix[0,4]:='A4';Matrix[0,5]:='A5';Matrix[0,6]:='A6';Matrix[0,7]:='A7';

     Matrix[1,0]:='B0';Matrix[1,1]:='B1';Matrix[1,2]:='B2';Matrix[1,3]:='B3';Matrix[1,4]:='B4';Matrix[1,5]:='B5';Matrix[1,6]:='B6';Matrix[1,7]:='B7';

and so on ...

it works , but it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: No, you do not want to create some sort of matrix.

Comment: Why not? strings are predefined phrases i need to access in runtime after press a global hotkey

Comment: You have been shown an example. If you can't understand how can we help? Try harder.

Comment: Why are you trying to build a constant, or  even hard-code this in? You can programmatically fill the array with two for loops quickly and easily, with far less clutter and noise.

Comment: I can fill the array with two loops if i want strings to Be like the exemple above.

my strings are like.
"kkksjjieo" , "romeo" , "this is a script" ... etcetc.
i cant see how i can fill the array with two loops like that.

Don't constants consume less resources than vars?

I'll take a look at the example again...

Comment: Your question is getting more and more unclear by the minute.

Comment: Furthermore you can create the string on the fly like this: `Chr(Ord('A')+col) + Chr(Ord('0')+row)`. But if you want a typed const do as the documentation says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way of storing an "array of records" at design-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481318/best-way-of-storing-an-array-of-records-at-design-time)

Answer (score 8):

The specific problem in your code is that the array you are declaring is **dynamic**.  That is, the bounds are not fixed and can be changed at run-time.

In older versions of Delphi (XE6 and earlier) is it simply not possible to declare dynamic array constants.  In XE7 and later it is possible but the syntax is different than for fixed array constants.

In all versions, if you declare a constant array with specified (and therefore fixed) bounds you can then specify the contents of the constant array thus:

```
const
  Matrix : array[0..7, 0..7] of String = 
   (
    ('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'),
    ('B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'),
    ('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'),
    ('D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7'),
    ('E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7'),
    ('F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7'),
    ('G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7'),
    ('H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7')
   );
```

If your array *needs* to be dynamic in a version of Delphi earlier than XE6 then you *cannot* initialise such an array with a declaration like this.

If you are using Delphi XE7 or later, then you can use the alternate syntax for declaring a dynamic array constant.  This is very similar to the syntax for a fixed array constant but uses square braces `[]` instead of regular parentheses `()`:

```
 const
   Matrix : array of array of String =
   [
    ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
    ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
    ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
    ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7'],
    ['E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7'],
    ['F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7'],
    ['G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7'],
    ['H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7']
   ];
```

### Hybrid Solution for Older Delphi Versions

If you are using an older version of Delphi then even with a dynamic array, if you have some initial state (bounds and content) that you would like to initialise it with then you could use a fixed array **constant** to define that initial state and then initialise your dynamic array at run-time from that constant, something like:

```
const
  MX_DIM  = 8;
  MX_DEFAULT : array[0..MX_DIM - 1, 0..MX_DIM - 1] of String =
   (
    ('A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'),
    ('B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'),
    ('C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'),
    ('D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7'),
    ('E0', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', 'E7'),
    ('F0', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7'),
    ('G0', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6', 'G7'),
    ('H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7')
   );

// Then in your code:

var
  x, y: Integer;
  Matrix: array of array of String;
begin
  // Initialise 'Matrix' from MX_DEFAULT:

  SetLength(Matrix, MX_DIM, MX_DIM);
  for x := 0 to Pred(MX_DIM) do
    for y := 0 to Pred(MX_DIM) do
      Matrix[x, y] := MX_DEFAULT[x, y];
end;
```

Comment: Actually, in Delphi Seattle (or was it XE8?) and newer, you can declare dynamic array constants, just like you can declare string constants (strings are -- special -- dynamic arrays too, after all), using the `[ ... ]` syntax, instead of `( ... )`.

Comment: It was XE7 in fact

Comment: RIP Rudy Velthuis

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Array_Constants) shows how to declare constant arrays

> **Array Constants**
>
> To declare an array constant, enclose the values of the elements of
>   the array, separated by commas, in parentheses at the end of the
>   declaration. These values must be represented by constant expressions.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> const Digits: array[0..9] of Char =
>   ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
> ```
>
> declares a typed constant called Digits that holds an array of
>   characters.
>
> To define a multidimensional array constant, enclose the values of
>   each dimension in a separate set of parentheses, separated by commas.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> type 
>   TCube = array[0..1, 0..1, 0..1] of Integer;
>
> const 
>   Maze: TCube = (((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((4, 5), (6,7)));
> ```
>
> creates an array called Maze where:
>
> ```
> Maze[0,0,0] = 0
> Maze[0,0,1] = 1
> Maze[0,1,0] = 2
> Maze[0,1,1] = 3
> Maze[1,0,0] = 4
> Maze[1,0,1] = 5
> Maze[1,1,0] = 6
> Maze[1,1,1] = 7
> ```

These examples are for one dimensional and three dimensional arrays. For a two dimensional array it would be:

```
const
  Coords: array [0..2, 0..2] of string = (
    ('A0', 'A1', 'A2'),
    ('B0', 'B1', 'B2'),
    ('C0', 'C1', 'C2'),
  );
```